# Advanced Installer тихий режим установки программы

Tags: windowsinstaller

Хотел сделать тихую установку VLC player. Использовал Advanced Installer. В результате получил .msi файл. На официальном [сайте](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) я просмотрел как правильно запускать msi и мне нужен конкретно запуск.

`msiexec.exe /i "C:\Example.msi" /qn`

я прописал команду, но установка не произошла.
Попробывал другой вариант с ключом

`msiexec.exe /i "C:\Example.msi" /passive`

програма запустила установку, но показывает окно установке, а я хочу это в тихом режиме установить. В чем проблема?

Или же .exe файл с ключом `/silenst` тоже не запускаеться

Comment: Что такое "/silenst" вообще? Может, /quiet - как описано в документации?

Comment: /quiet это для .msi а /silenst для .exe.